# How to access application from controller in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How can I access javafx Application class from a Controller class? If I go into more specific I need to keep one stage and switch scenes.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the following on an arbitrary node of your scene to get the current stage.

```
Node.getScene().getWindow()
```

It will give you an object from type Window. (Stage subclasses Window)

Or you hand over the stage from outside of the controller:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
    "Main.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
MainController controller = new MainController()
controller.setStage(stage);
fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
try {
    fxmlLoader.load();
} catch (IOException exception) {
    throw new RuntimeException(exception);
}
```